# Continous integration tool for rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration

We would like to use a continuous build integration tool for our `rails` project. Would like to know if there are any options which will allow us to run this in a `cloud` environment or locally.

Comment: See semaphore and travis

Comment: Not sure why it was closed, the question has been answered by few people. If someone at-least can state what wasn't clear, it will help me fine tune the question going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Circle](https://circleci.com) is an [advanced CI service for Rails](https://circleci.com) (and other web apps). It runs in the cloud, and you'll have your first test results in about 20 seconds.

Joel and I spent a while chatting about this on the [Stackoverflow podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/se-podcast-22/) - [check it out](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/se-podcast-22/)!